# Can I plot Euler angles in rxbag?

Tags: ros, quaternion, rxbag, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use rxbag to plot the yaw angle I obtain from a localization algorithm, however the orientation in geometry_msgs::PoseStamped (and most other messages) is given in quaternions. Is it possible to somehow convert that to  directly to Euler angles to plot them in the GUI?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48417/can-i-plot-euler-angles-in-rxbag?/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the script listed at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11545/plotprint-rpy-from-quaternion/#17106) to subscribe to quaternions that are published from your bag file, convert them to Euler angles, and then republish as RPY in NWU coordinates. You can then plot your Euler angles with rxplot. Use the same node multiple times while remapping topics and you can visualize Euler angles from multiple sources simultaneously.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-15**:
many thanks!